# Windows service - only one instance to allow at a time

Tags: c#, windows, service

I tried with below code to restrict the second instance of the windows service, but below code is not working for me, can anyone help me out.
I have put time interval to run service, that is 5 mints, if first instance is started and running, after 5 mints second instance is starts even though first instance is not completed.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

     bool ok;
     System.Threading.Mutex m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "ImageImportService", out ok);
        if (!ok)
        {
            return;
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(m);
        if (PriorProcess() != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new ImageImportService() 
            };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
    public static Process PriorProcess()
    {
        Process curr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(curr.ProcessName);
        foreach (Process p in procs)
        {
            if ((p.Id != curr.Id) && (p.MainModule.FileName == curr.MainModule.FileName))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for 2 instances of the same service to run?

Comment: How is it not working?  Exactly what is failing?

Comment: I have put time interval to run service , that is 5 mins, if first instance is started and running, ofter 5 mins second instance is starts even first instance is not cimpleted.

Comment: You call `GC.KeepAlive(m)` too early. Your mutex object may be garbage-collected and finalized, releasing the mutex, immediately after the call.

Comment: where i need to call GC.KeepAlive(m) method.

Answer (score 1):

Service Control Manager, a component of Windows, does not allow starting a Windows service if it is already running.  Just rely on it.

The main thing you need to do is to never launch your executable directly.  Instead, use the `ServiceController` class, when starting the service from code, and Control Panel (`services.msc`) when starting/stopping it manually.

In some cases, you may need to take extra steps to make sure that the service does not keep any resources behind after it has been stopped, preventing its own subsequent startup until some lower level timeout.  But nothing in your question indicates that you already ran into such issues (e.g., rebinding a TCP port).